# Providing Walking Directions in iOS 6 Using MapKit

Tags: ios, mapkit

I realise that iOS 6 is still under NDA so i'll keep my question succinct and to the point.

Is there a way to provide walking directions within my own application without using Maps.app? I know I can send requests to Maps.app to display directions but i'd like to be able to provide directions from my own application if at all possible?

There are a handful of new classes in iOS 6 that look like they might do what I want but i'm unable to test them currently. I'll have a looksee and try to implement something but I want to be sure it's even possible before wasting time.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iOS 6 is well and truly out of NDA now, I can safely say that providing walking directions in your own application is definitely not possible.

You can however open Maps.app with a properly formatted request to provide directions if required.